# Internal Server Error 500 -- EC2, django, nginx, uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, internal-server-error

I'm developing and deploying django based web-app through EC2 with nginx and uwsgi.

Because of developing Front-side (based on react), I send several http request to my server's public IPv4.
And the first few moment, my request is normally answered by server. All data is safely delivered to "http://localhost:3000".

But in some reason, after rebooting my EC2 instance, my nginx returned "500 (Internal Server Error)". More detailed information is descripted below.

**[log]**

1. /var/nginx/access.log --> any further information than internal server error

```
3.21.102.102 - - [22/Dec/2022:04:07:08 +0000] "GET /beta/.env HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246" "-"
3.21.102.102 - - [22/Dec/2022:04:07:08 +0000] "GET /beta/.env.local HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246" "-"
3.21.102.102 - - [22/Dec/2022:04:07:09 +0000] "GET /beta/.env.production HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246" "-"
3.21.102.102 - - [22/Dec/2022:04:07:09 +0000] "GET /beta/.env.staging HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246" "-"
3.21.102.102 - - [22/Dec/2022:04:07:09 +0000] "GET /live/.env HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246" "-"
```

2. /var/nginx/access.log --> empty

**[configure files and django settings.py]**

1. nginx.configure

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  {{server_address_of_mine}};
        root         /home/ec2-user/cury_engine;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


         location / {

                include         uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/ec2-user/cury.sock;

        }

    }
```

2. django settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cury_engine.wsgi.application'


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    "http://localhost:8000",
    '{{my_domain}}',
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
```

**[What I tried after reboot server]**

1. `sudo systemctl restart nginx`
2. `sudo systemctl restart nginx.service`
3. `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi` (my django server is automatically run server with this command)
4. `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi.service`
   -> I check nginx and uwsgi is running safely. (with `sudo systemctl status XXX` command)

**[What I tried differently to test server status]**

1. postman request --> same result: 500 (Internal Server Error)
2. curl request inside EC2 instance terminal --> same result: 500 (Internal Server Error)

i expect to recover my server and know how to debug this error

Comment: What does your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting look like?

Comment: Have you looked in the nginx error log?

Comment: please use place holders for your server details. Don't make it public.  you can use  like <my-ec2-instance-ip> while post questions

Comment: @Selcuk, I contained public IPv4 address and localhost like address into "ALLOWED_HOSTS"

Comment: @JohnGordon, My nginx error log is empty, only access log describes what happend

Comment: @Jisson, Thx!! I will immediately edit that informations

Comment: Have you also checked the uwsgi error log?